# A question about the derivatives of the Möbius inversion formula for $\zeta(s)$

Tags: number-theory, derivatives, riemann-zeta, mobius-inversion

The following expression for the $\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}$ involving the [Möbius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function) is well known:

$$\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac {\mu(n)}{n^s} \qquad s \in \mathbb{C},\Re(s) > 1$$

There also exists this (recursive) mobius inversion formula for $\zeta(s)$:

\begin{align}
\zeta(s) &= 1+\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } {\frac {{\mu} \left( k \right) 
}{k}\sum _{m=1}^{\infty }{\frac {\zeta \left( kms \right) -1}{m}}}\qquad s \in \mathbb{C},\Re(s) >0, s \ne \frac{1}{i}, i \in \mathbb{N}\\
\text{where the $d$-th derivative is:}\\
\zeta^{d}(s) &= \sum _{k=1}^{\infty } {{\mu} \left( k \right) 
\sum _{m=1}^{\infty }{\zeta^{d}\left( kms \right)}} (km)^{d-1} \qquad d \in \mathbb{N}, d > 0\\
\text{which is simplest for $d=1$:}\\
\zeta^{1}(s) &= \sum _{k=1}^{\infty } {{\mu} \left( k \right) 
\sum _{m=1}^{\infty }{\zeta^{1}\left( kms \right)}}\\
\end{align}

Observe that in all equations, $k=m=1$ already yields the LHS, hence the remaining series must always sum to $0$.

**Questions:**

1. Could any of these expressions be simplified further (I have tried swapping the sums, which worked fine, however didn't help simplifying things further)?
2. Taking the anti-derivates for $d$, always correctly recreates the $d-1$ derivative except for the step from $d=1$ to $d=0$ (i.e. when the constants $1$ and $-1$ have to re-appear). Is there a reason for why that final step to $d=0$ is more complicated?

Comment: With respect to question (2), consider the Dirichlet series $F(s)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n\ n^{-s}$ where $a_n=1$ for $F(s)=\zeta(s)$ and $a_n=(-1)^d\ \log^d(n)$ for $F(s)=\zeta^{(d)}(s)$. Note that $a_1=1$ for $F(s)=\zeta(s)$, but $a_1=0$ for $F(s)=\zeta^{(d)}(s)$. For $F(s)=\zeta(s)$ the coefficient $a_n=(-1)^0\ \log^0(n)$ works for all values of $n$ except $n=1$ since $(-1)^0\ \log^0(1)=0^0$ which is indeterminate. So perhaps the constants $1$ and/or $-1$ in the formula for $\zeta(s)$ are related to this observation.